# MongoDB Issues on Yosemite

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I typed in two commands, `mongo` and `mongod` and get the following results. Not sure how to fix this

```
mahtabalam$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: test
2015-09-19T18:59:35.315-0400 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-09-19T18:59:35.316-0400 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
mahtabalam$ mongod
2015-09-19T19:00:47.133-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:13 Permission denied
2015-09-19T19:00:47.134-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2015-09-19T19:00:47.134-0400 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Update 1:

After trying `sudo mongod --dbpath="Users/mahtabalam/Sites/mongo/data/db` and then pressing `ctrl + c` on my macbook pro, and then re-entering `mongod` has yielded the following:

```
2015-09-19T21:54:49.819-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.820-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.836-0400 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.836-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=28979 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Mahtabs-MacBook-Pro.local
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.836-0400 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.836-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.836-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.837-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.6
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.837-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.837-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Darwin yosemitevm.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.837-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.837-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
    2015-09-19T21:54:49.850-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Comment: try with sudo command

Answer (score 2):

`mongod` command starts the DB server & it expects an argument `dbpath` so the full command would be `sudo mongod --dbath="dblocation/data/db"` where `/data/db` is mandatory to start the server.
Whereas `mongo` opens a mongo db shell where you can execute your db statements

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested and it led me to Update 1 if you check my post above. I don't think it quite worked

Comment: you haven't noticed the bottom of the log it says `waiting for connections on port 27017 ` which means mongodb server is started and its waiting for the new connections. you can now run `mongo` from the new window this command helps you to connect to the server.

Comment: Thanks!!! :) Sorry I just didn't know that `waiting for connection on port 27017` meant that I am connected to the server. I am a newb still but still plowing through. Thanks again